# How to use Redis in unit testing?

Tags: asp.net, unit-testing, redis

Suppose I have a method in my controller class that updates the score of a key,value pair in a Redis database. I want to write a unit test to check if the score is not null and is incremented by 1. I just want to see how unit testing works with Redis and how you extract the score from a particular key, value pair and check its validity.

Controller Class //When user refreshes api/do/v1/togglelike/{id}", the score is updated in redis for that user and is incremented by 1;

```
[HttpGet]
        [Route("api/do/v1/togglelike/{id}")]
        public IHttpActionResult ToggleLike(String id)
        {
            var currentUser = "mike";


            var likeSet = redis1.SortedSetRangeByScore("likes:" + id);
            var likeStatus = redis1.SortedSetScore("likes:" + id, currentUser);

            //Current user has not yet liked the profile
            if (likeStatus == null)
            {
                redis1.SortedSetAdd("likes:" + id, currentUser, 1);
                return Ok("Like Added");

            }
            /*redis1.SortedSetAdd("likes:" + id, currentUser, 1);
            return Ok("Like Added");*/
            else
            {
                double counter = redis1.SortedSetIncrement("likes:" + id, currentUser, 1);
                 redis1.SortedSetAdd("likes:" + id, currentUser, counter);
                 return Ok("Like Added");
                /*redis1.SortedSetRemove("likes:" + id, currentUser);
                return Ok("Like Removed");*/
            }
        }
```

Test Class: I want to get the score from the key,value pair and check that it is equal to a valid number;

```
namespace VideoControllerTest
{
    [TestClass]
    public class VideoControllerTest
    {
         IDatabase redis1;

        public VideoControllerTest()
        {
            redis1 = RedisFactory.Connection.GetDatabase();
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void VideoController_Adview()
        {
            //Arrange
            VideoController controller = new VideoController();
            //Act
            IHttpActionResult actionResult = controller.ToggleLike("video123");

            //Assert; Check to see the counter is incremented by 1 and is not null;

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to be able to unit test external system (in this case a redis database),  you have to mock the external system.

If the `redis1` is an interface, you could easily mock it with a framework like Mock, if it's an implementation this would be hard and you have to wrap it with your own class in order to mock it.

you need to pass the IDatabase into the controller, so I have added another constructor.

```
class VideoController
{
    private IDatabase redis1;

    public VideoController(IDatabase db)
    {
        this.redis1 = db;
    }
}
```

Test method should be as follows

```
//note : library used for mocking is moq (https://github.com/Moq/moq4)
        [TestMethod]
        public void VideoController_Adview()
        {
        //Arrange
            Mock<IDatabase> mockRedis = new Mock<IDatabase>();
            //set existing score as null
            mockRedis.Setup(r => r.SortedSetScore(It.isAny<string>,It.isAny<string>)).Returns(null); 

            VideoController controller = new VideoController(mockRedis.Object);


            //Act
            IHttpActionResult actionResult = controller.ToggleLike("video123");
            //verify added once
            mockRedis.Verify(r => r.SortedSetAdd("likes:videio123",1), Times.Once());
        }
```

Comment: I am using StackExchange.redis. I am assuming it is an interface. Is there a "get" method I can use to extract the score for a particular key,value?

Comment: not really, but you could intercept the addition of the key and value

Comment: I am confused about the flow. The user has to first enter the url route in the browser in order for the score in the database to increment. Is there a way to check that the score was incremented by 1? What would this look like in my [TestMethod] stub? I am not sure IHttpActionResult actionResult = controller.ToggleLike("video123"); does anything or updates the database as the score only increments if the user goes to the URL specified in the route. I am just stuck on what the syntax would look like in my VideoController Test class. I am using MSTest.

Comment: Please refer to the edits in the answer, I have added sample code

Answer (score 3):

Mocking Redis is great for testing the next layer, but it's a complex thing and you're likely to spend a lot of time testing your mock rather than your production implementation.

Instead set up a local instance of Redis for wherever you run your tests, add a prefix for your keys, then use a `SCAN` to clean them up. So (using StackExchange.Redis in the test)...

```
// In your test setup
VideoController.Prefix = "test:";
// Then create your testing data in Redis

// In your code include the prefix
var likeSet = redis1.SortedSetRangeByScore(Prefix + "likes:" + id);

// In your test cleanup:
// Get the server, as SCAN/KEYS will only run across one server
var server = redis.GetServer("localhost", 6379);

// Get all the keys with the test prefix
var testKeys = server.Keys(pattern: "test:*");

 // Delete all the keys, with wait because we don't want fire&forget
Task.WaitAll((from k in testKeys select db.KeyDeleteAsync(k)).ToArray());
```

This does something that is very bad practice in production, as the `KEYS` or `SCAN` operation will only run for one Redis server, `KEYS` will run synchronously and block while it runs. It should be fine in a unit test though, as long as you don't have the production Redis in the same location.

Comment: Another similar approach would be to use separate database index for tests and just `flushdb` whole database. This would save you from adding prefixes everywhere.